# was5 resources.xml

Tags: java, jsp, websphere

is there a way to read this file inside a JSP/Servlet?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a SAXParser, but what are you trying to do specifically?  The supported public API for accessing the configuration tree is [ConfigService](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v5r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/javadoc/ae/com/ibm/websphere/management/configservice/ConfigService.html).